# awk String comparison is not working

Tags: awk

I am getting all the lines as output. The if condition of the following code is not working.

```
grep -Ev '^(halt|sync|shutdown)' /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{\
    if("$7"!="$(which nologin)") \
        { print $0; } \
    }'
```

I tried with different if conditions:

This is also returning all the values.

```
if("$1"!="usbmux") \
        { print $1; } \
```

But this is not returning anything even though there is one usbmux entry in $1.

```
if("$1"=="usbmux") \
        { print $1; } \
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a general note, it is rarely necessary to use combinations of `grep` and `awk` in a piped command; usually, `awk` is capable of doing everything by itself, and using only one program can help prevent a lot of mistakes (I've had my share of experience with that ;) ).

Comment: You probably want to read the first 40 pages of the "GNU Awk User's Guide", especially the excellent examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `awk`, don't quote variables.

```
awk -F : '$1 == "usbmux"'
```

This would print all lines whose first `:`-delimited field is exactly the string `usbmux`. The default action is to print the current record (line, by default) if no explicit action is associated with a condition.

```
awk -F : -v string="$( command -v nologin )" '$7 == string'
```

This would print all lines whose 7th `:`-delimited field is the path to the `nologin` utility.  The `awk` variable `string` is set to the output of `command -v nologin` on the command line with `-v`.

```
awk -F : -v string="$( command -v nologin )" '$1 !~ /^(halt|sync|shutdown)$/ && $7 == string'
```

This does the same as the command above it, but it avoids the lines whose first field is one of `halt`, `sync` or `shutdown` (without using `grep`).

I used `command -v nologin` to get the path of the `nologin` utility rather than `which`, see "[Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)" for why.